# Example of a data structure with lazy spine and strict leaves

Tags: haskell, data-structures

One of the performance trick mentioned [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10209798) is this:

> As a safe default: lazy in the spine, strict in the leaves.

I'm having trouble imagining such a data structure.

If I take Lists as an example, and if I make it strict in the leaves then won't the spine will be automatically strict ?

Is there any data structure example where the spine is lazy and leaves are strict ?

Comment: `repeat 1` is an example of a lazy spine and strict leaves.

Comment: I'm guessing the author just meant something like `data List a = Empty | Cons !a (List a)`.

Comment: @user5402 What about `repeat (1 + 3)` ? I guess it has lazy spine and lazy leaf then ?

Comment: Perhaps. Note if `1+3` is not polymorphic then GHC may decide to evaluate it itself. How about this: `repeat undefined`.  This program will run without throwing an exception: `print $ length $ take 10 $ repeat undefined`. If you don't like `undefined`, you can substitute `repeat (error "boo!")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Lazy in the spine, strict in the leaves" is a property of the *API*, not (just) a property of the data structure. Here's an example of how it might look for lists:

```
module StrictList (StrictList, runStrictList, nil, cons, uncons, repeat) where

newtype StrictList a = StrictList { runStrictList :: [a] }

nil :: StrictList a
nil = StrictList []

cons :: a -> StrictList a -> StrictList a
cons x (StrictList xs) = x `seq` StrictList (x:xs)

uncons :: StrictList a -> Maybe (a, StrictList a)
uncons (StrictList []) = Nothing
uncons (StrictList (x:xs)) = Just (x, StrictList xs)

repeat :: a -> StrictList a
repeat x = x `seq` StrictList (let xs = x:xs in xs)
```

Note that compared to built-in lists, this API is a quite impoverished -- that's just to keep the illustration small, not for a fundamental reason. The key point here is that you can still support things like `repeat`, where the spine is necessarily lazy (it's infinite!) but all the leaves are evaluated before anything else happens. Many of the other list operations that can produce infinite lists can be adapted to leaf-strict versions (though not all, as you observe).

You should also notice that it is not necessarily possible to take a leaf-lazy, spine-lazy structure and turn it into a leaf-strict, spine-lazy one in a natural way; e.g. one could not write a generic `fromList :: [a] -> StrictList a` such that:

- `fromList (repeat x) = repeat x` and
- `runStrictList (fromList xs) = xs` for all finite-length `xs`.

(Forgive my punning, I'm a `repeat` offender).

Answer (score 3):

This bit of advice mixes up two related, but distinct, ideas. Haskell programmers are often sloppy about the distinction, but it matters here.

#### Strict vs. non-strict

This is a semantic distinction. A function `f` is *strict* if `f _|_ = _|_`, and non-strict otherwise.

#### Eager (call by value) vs. lazy (call by need)

This is a matter of implementation, and can have major performance implications. Lazy evaluation is one way to implement non-strict semantics.

#### What the claim really means

It actually means that the data structure should be *strict* and *lazy*. The right amount of laziness in the spine of a data structure can be very helpful. Sometimes it gives asymptotic improvements in performance. It can also improve cache utilization and cut garbage collection costs. On the other hand, too much laziness (even in the spine, in some cases!) can lead to a harmful accumulation of deferred computations. From an API standpoint, it can be very helpful to ensure that insertion operations are eager (and therefore strict), so that you know that everything stored in the structure has been forced.

Comment: first let me say: very good remark/answer - thanks! But while you said when a function is **strict** you did not say when a structure is - maybe you should add this? // OT: IMO this stuff is almost as *crazy* (commonly misunderstood) as the weak vs. strong typing *definition* (which AFAIK does not exist) - for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Normal_order) gives *strict* not only for the semantics but also to differentiate between the major evaluation strategies and I think most programmers get this too (fewer know about the semantics stuff)